# Insert parent child record using transaction [Executing successfully but record not inserted]

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to insert records into hierarchical tables using transaction. After executing its showing command completed successfully but records are not inserted into tables. Please see below script if missing something:

```
CREATE TABLE dev_emp_master
(
id int identity(1,1) primary key, 
name char(2)
)
GO
CREATE TABLE dev_emp_child
(
id int identity(1,1) primary key, 
mid int foreign key references dev_emp_master(id),
addr char(3)
)

BEGIN TRANSACTION [T_MIGRATION]
BEGIN TRY
DECLARE @masterId INT;
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[dev_emp_master] OFF;
INSERT INTO dev_emp_master (name) VALUES('A');
SET @masterId = scope_identity();
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[dev_emp_child] OFF;
INSERT INTO dev_emp_child(mid,addr) VALUES(@masterId,'ABC');
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[dev_emp_child] ON;
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[dev_emp_master] ON;
COMMIT TRANSACTION [T_MIGRATION]
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
ROLLBACK TRANSACTION [T_MIGRATION]
END CATCH
GO
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (sql server?)

Comment: @jarlh: MS SQL SERVER

Comment: You are suppressing error message by yourself. And no idea what are you playing with those `IDENTITY_INSERT` switches for.

Comment: @IvanStarostin: Got the issue. But is there any way to avoid this? Because anyway I've to on identity if done off already.

Comment: `I've to on identity`... why? remove all of those lines. `OFF` and `ON`.

Comment: Identity Insert is off by default, its only "On" if you set it on during the session. If your solution requires you to manually insert identity values, its better off not declaring the column as identity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[dev_emp_child] ON;
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[dev_emp_master] ON;
```

That is the issue. Identity_Insert cannot be turned on for two tables at the same time.

You can easily troubleshoot your code if you put a

```
 Print ERROR_MESSAGE()
```

in your catch block.

Comment: Oh! got it. But is there any way to avoid this? Because anyway I've to on identity if done off already.

Comment: I guess you are getting confused :  IDENTITY_INSERT ON means you can manually insert a value into the identity column. OFF means SQL Server controls the identity value